# Flutter Web: App isn't loading on Firebase custom domain

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

i hosted my app on Firebase hosting but when i launch the default site  "name.web.app" the flutter app works fine, but after i used custom domain, i end up getting this error on the console `"manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 "`
and the website shows a white page, not even loading. This is only happening on custom domain the default "name.web.app" still works!